# Risks of Unplugging Lennox HealthClimate Unit

Tags: hvac, air-quality, air-filter

I bought a home with a space age lookin' Lennox HVAC.  Instead of using a basic paper air filter like you can get at a local department store, the unit has a *big* paper air filter and a photocatalysis unit.  The photocatalysis unit consists of 4 pricey Ultra Violet bulbs and an expensive honey-comb titanium-dioxide catalyst insert assembly.  Both the paper air filter *and* the photocatalysis unit are housed in the same "Healthy Climate" (R) container.  The Healthy Climate container has to be plugged in so the UV Bulbs can be powered on 24 hours a day 7 days a week.

I *suspect* my duct-work leading from my HVAC unit to the vents in my home are somewhat leaky so I think it is pointless to try to obtain near "perfect" air at the unit itself.

Would it be okay for me to:

1. remove the bulbs and honeycomb pattern catalyst from my "Healthy Climate" (R) container
2. Leave the *big* huge paper filter in the "Healthy Climate" (R) container
3. run my Lennox HVAC with the "Healthy Climate" (R) container
   unplugged?

If I *do* choose to run my Lennox HVAC with no UV Bulbs and no honey-comb titanium-dioxide catalyst, would I compromise my family's health or the integrity of my master HVAC unit?

Comment: Most homes only have dust filters to protect the furnace and evaporator coil from being filled with dust. The UV lamps are an extra level that is really not needed but can prevent mold and rare things like legoniars ? Not sure on spelling. If your system is clean and the condensation drains work well removing the lamps won't put your family at risk. If you or a family member has any kind of health issues that are breathing/ lung related this system is worth the cost, if not a standard filter is fine.

Comment: Your comment almost reads like an answer.